# Threading in C, cross platform

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, cross-platform

I am dealing with an existing project (in C) that is currently running on a single thread, and we would like to run on multiple platforms AND have multiple threads. Hopefully, there is a library for this, because, IMHO, the Win32 API is like poking yourself in the eye repeatedly. I know about Boost.Thread for C++, but, this must be C (and compilable on MinGW and gcc). Cygwin is not an option, sorry.

Comment: If you think that `CreateThread` is poking yourself in the eye repeatedly you should not be attempting this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/) API, it's multi-platform and you can compile it with GCC.

Brief description from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP):

> OpenMP (Open Multi-Processing) is an application programming interface
>   (API) that supports multi-platform shared memory multiprocessing
>   programming in C, C++, and Fortran,[3] on most platforms, processor
>   architectures and operating systems, including Solaris, AIX, HP-UX,
>   Linux, macOS, and Windows. It consists of a set of compiler
>   directives, library routines, and environment variables that influence
>   run-time behavior.

Comment: After over a year with OpenMP, I can assure everyone who reads this question that it is 100% worth the time.

Comment: Broken link, Tried to edit , but the site says i should at least edit 6 characters...

Answer (score 9):

I would use the POSIX thread API - pthread.  This article has some hints for implementing it on Windows, and a header-file-only download (BSD license):

http://locklessinc.com/articles/pthreads_on_windows/

Edit: I used the sourceforge pthreads-win32 project in the past for multi-platform threading and it worked really nicely.  Things have moved on since then and the above link seems more up-to-date, though I haven't tried it.  This answer assumes of course that pthreads are available on your non-Windows targets (for Mac / Linux I should think they are, probably even embedded)

Answer (score 4):

Windows threading has sufficiently different functionality when compared to that of Linux such that perhaps you should consider two different implementations, at least if application performance could be an issue. On the other hand, simply implementing multi-threading may well make your app slower than it was before. Lets assume that performance is an issue and that multi-threading is the best option.

With Windows threads I'm specifically thinking of I/O Completion Ports (IOCPs) which allow implementing I/O-event driven threads that make the most efficient use of the hardware.

Many "classic" applications are constructed along one thread/one socket (/one user or similar) concept where the number of simultaneous sessions will be limited by the scheduler's ability to handle large numbers of threads (>1000). The IOCP concept allows limiting the number of threads to the number of cores in your system which means that the scheduler will have very little to do. The threads will only execute when the IOCP releases them after an I/O event has occurred. The thread services the IOC, (typically) initiates a new I/O and returns to wait at the IOCP for the next completion. Before releasing a thread the IOCP will also provide the context of the completion such that the thread will "know" what processing context the IOC belongs to.

The IOCP concept completely does away with polling which is a great resource waster although "wait on multiple object" polling is somewhat of an improvement. The last time I looked Linux had nothing remotely like IOCPs so a Linux multi-threaded application would be constructed quite differently compared to a Windows app with IOCPs.

In really efficient IOCP apps there is a risk that so many IOs (or rather Outputs) are queued to the IO resource involved that the system runs out of non-paged memory to store them. Conversely, in really inefficient IOCP apps there is a risk that so many Inputs are queued (waiting to be serviced) that the non-paged memory is exhausted when trying to temporarily buffer them.

Answer (score 3):

The "best"/"simplest"/... answer here is definitely pthreads. It's the native threading architecture on Unix/POSIX systems and works almost as good on Windows. No need to look any further.

Comment: Will it compile on windows without using the win32 API?

Comment: There is no threading possible on Windows without using the Win32 API, just like there is no threading possible on Unix without some kernel hackery or using the pthreads API. Do you have to worry about the Win32 API in your application? No, that's why there's a pthreads-win32 library, delivered with MinGW. Keep in mind that while the library works with MSVC, it's not part of the Windows SDK you get with Visual Studio. But I implicitely assumed you would be using MinGW.

Answer (score 3):

If someone needs a portable and lightweight solution for threading in C, take a look at the [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys/wiki) library. It provides you thread management and synchronization, as well as other useful features like portable socket implementation. All major operating systems (Windows, Linux, OS X) are supported, various other less popular operating systems are also supported (i.e. AIX, HP-UX, Solaris, QNX, IRIX, etc). On every platform only the native calls are used to minimize the overheads. The library is fully covered with Unit tests which are run on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

[glib threads](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html) can be compiled cross-platforms.

Comment: Never again will I use a object wrapper for C. I'm done with glib, sorry.

Comment: It's used all over the place. What was your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are constrained with C. I have two suggestions:

1) I have a seen a project (similar to yours) that had to run on Windows and Linux with threads. The way it was written was that it (the same codebase) used pthreads on Linux and win32 threads on Windows. This was achieved by a conditional #ifdef statement wherever threads needed to be created such as

```
#ifdef WIN32

//use win32 threads

#else

//use pthreads

#endif
```

2) The second suggestion might be to use OpenMP. Have you considered OpenMP at all?

Please let me know if I missed something or if you want more details. I am happy to help.

Best,
Krishna

Comment: If I wanted to do that, then I would not have asked for the library, since I said I wanted something that did not use the win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, multi threading in C for windows is heavily tied to Win32 APIs. Other  languages like C# and JAVA supported by a framework also tie into these core libraries while offering their thread classes.

However, I did find an openthreads API platform on sourceforge which might help you:

http://openthreads.sourceforge.net/

The API is modeled with respect to the Java and POSIX thread standard,

I have not tried this myself as I currently do not have a need to support multiple platforms on my C/C++ projects.