# Is there a cross-platform framework for C?

Tags: frameworks, cross-platform

I am curious to know if there is any kind of programming library/framework for the C language for cross-platform programming of course. I mean there are already frameworks like Wxwidgets, Boost, Qt, U++ and etc for C++ available but I have not yet found any for C .

**Updated Info:**

We are trying to build an underlying Framework/library to be used in our project. We are going to eliminate the dotnet and instead provide a counterpart for those libraries which is fast and less demanding.

We will be working on a server/client based project, and thus the underlying services must be fast and also portable. GUI is not our priority now, but libraries providing threading capabilities is of importance to us.

And for the ANSI part, I think we are fine with that at the moment unless something changes that in the future.

Comment: thank you , but isn't gtk+ a GUI toolkit only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write plain ANSI C, it should work on every POSIX system. 
The most successful example of cross platform C library is standard C library itself (IMHO).

If you're looking for GUI toolkit GTK is the answer, 
if you're looking for terminal UI, ncurses is pretty portable.

If you're looking for general use libraries, as long as they're written in ANSI C, should work almost everywhere, as long as it doesn't use system level APIs.

Can you just tell us, what kind of library/framework you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you ,. we are trying to build an underlying Framework/library to be used in our project. we are going to eliminate the dotnet and instead , provide a counterpart for those libraries which is fast and less demanding . 
we will be working on a server /client based project, and thus the underlying services must be fast and also portable . GUI is not  our priority now, but libraries providing threading capabilities is of importance to us . 
and for the ANSI part , i think we are fine with that at the moment unless sth changes that in the future.

Comment: @Hossein try looking at answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613646/threading-in-c-cross-platform you may find some useful link to libs

Comment: Thanks , i think i stick to that OpenMP for while . 
so far OPenMp and Glib seem to be sufficient. 
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

[GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) is long established and actively maintained cross-platform C-only (or primarily) toolkit. You'll find not only on-line documentation but also books written about it. It is the framework backing up the [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/) project.

GTK+ is meant to build applications with UI, first of all. However, even if you don't need UI you'll find that some GTK+ components, namely [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/), provide general multiplatform support comparable with Qt. Actually, I needed a framework without UI at first and chose GLib over [APR](http://apr.apache.org/) because I was able to find documentation and tutorials easier.

GTK+ was initially developed on UN*X an X-Windows which remains the platform where you can get it running the most easily. I wouldn't say that it is more difficult on Windows; it is just that you have more compiling environment options. I started with prepared GTK+ packages and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) but ended up integrating GTK+ with MSVC.

GTK+ exists for a long time and some people may find it old-school. On the other hand, it shows that it has proven to be stable and useful. There are also bindings for [C++](http://www.gtkmm.org/) and [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp).

As with every big framework, the more you need from it the longer you will have to learn. But the other way round it works too; the more you learn the more you'll be able to do with it. Consistent coding style helps getting used to it.

--- Ferda

Comment: thank you very much , very informative indeed . 
i updated my post with the info on our purpose and need from asking such a question . 
GLib seems intersting , but we need sth which provides some more features , such as supporting the work with threads and the likes .

Comment: You're welcome. While GLib supports threads, and networking too, it wasn't developed primarily for performance. There are others specialized on client/server apps. [Another thread here](http://bit.ly/xjdFUR) refers to ACE, POCO and ASIO, e.g. All of them C++, I'm afraid... I evaluated [ASIO](http://think-async.com/Asio/) once, which I liked for using the quickest support on a particular OS, like IOCP on Windows. There are threads [here](http://bit.ly/HjidRO) and [here](http://bit.ly/HBybRF) about asynchronous IO.

Comment: thank you very much dear @Ferdinand Prantl .
Among those , it seems only the Glib is C friendly ( compatible - supoorting it ) the rest belog to C++ it seems . 
any way , i think between OpenMP and Glib , i'll be using OpenMP for now ,and if we needed more , we have Glib thanks to you :)